# saving values to a plist

Tags: iphone, ios, plist

I am currently reading though this tutorial [here](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/05/30/property-list-tutorial-using-plist-to-store-user-data/)

And in it he seems to be creating a plist file in the resources folder. then in the code he only ever uses that plist once to read from, then dynamically creates a new plist that he uses to store his values and read his value from in the future.

I would like to know if this is good or bad practice? shouldn't he just be using the plist file he created in his resource files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PLIST that’s included in the app bundle’s resources cannot be written to—iOS’s sandboxing rules prevent apps from modifying themselves. If your app wants to store files, it has to do so in areas that the sandbox allows it access to, such as the Documents directory used in that sample.

Comment: okay, I did not know that. I am just looking as saving several string values that I need to know when requesting data from my db, things like CacheID, Data version, request number etc. so its not really a user defaults thing.. So I think the best option is to create a new plist inside the documents dir and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot write to your resources folder.  You need to create the file elsewhere if you will be writing to it.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should just update the values in the existing Plist. You get a Plist for free. It's called NSUserDefaults. If you are just saving/reading a single value, this is the easiest way to do that. In your example, you should check for the existence of said file, and only create it if it doesn't exist.